# Lucene 5 Sort problems (UninvertedReader and DocValues)

Tags: java, sorting, search, lucene

I am working on a Search Engine built in Lucene 5.2.1, but I am having trouble with Sort updated option for Search. I get an error while searching with the Sort option:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'stars' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:208)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getNumeric(DocValues.java:227)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$NumericComparator.getNumericDocValues(FieldComparator.java:167)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$NumericComparator.doSetNextReader(FieldComparator.java:153)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.SimpleFieldComparator.getLeafComparator(SimpleFieldComparator.java:36)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue.getComparators(FieldValueHitQueue.java:183)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$NonScoringCollector.getLeafCollector(TopFieldCollector.java:141)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:762)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:485)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:694)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:679)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:621)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:527)
>       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577)
>       at SearchEngine.searchBusinessByCategory(SearchEngine.java:145)
>       at Tests.searchEngineTest(Tests.java:137)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:13)

I have indexed a document which contains a double field "stars" that I need to use to sort search results (the document with highest "stars" value needs to be on top).

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new DoubleField("stars", stars, Store.YES));
```

Then I implemented a Search command with Sort option on that "stars" field as follows:

```
SortField sortfield = new SortField("stars", SortField.Type.DOUBLE, true);
Sort sort = new Sort(sortfield);
mySearcher.search(query, maxdocs, sort);
```

I have found similar discussions online but they all talk about SolR (or sometimes Elastic Search) but they don't provide neither a Lucene snippet nor a more general implementative solution strategy for Lucene 5. For example:

> Solr uses DocValues and falls back to wrapping with UninvertingReader,
>   if user have not indexed them (with negative startup performance and
>   memory effects). But in general, you should really enable DocValues
>   for fields you want to sort on.
>   (from h[ttp://grokbase.com/t/lucene/java-user/152q2jcgzz/lucene-4-x-5-illegalstateexception-while-sorting](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/java-user/152q2jcgzz/lucene-4-x-5-illegalstateexception-while-sorting))

I see that I have to do something with UninvertingReader or DocValues. But what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a custom `FieldType` since the DoubleField constructor you are using does not store docvalues.

Ex:

```
private static final FieldType DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED = new FieldType();
static {
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setTokenized(true);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setOmitNorms(true);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED
        .setNumericType(FieldType.NumericType.DOUBLE);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setStored(true);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setDocValuesType(DocValuesType.NUMERIC);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.freeze();
}
```

And add to your doc using:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new DoubleField("stars", stars, DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED));
```

When you use

```
new DoubleField("stars", stars, Stored.YES);
```

You are actually using this `FieldType`:

```
public static final FieldType TYPE_STORED = new FieldType();
static {
    TYPE_STORED.setTokenized(true);
    TYPE_STORED.setOmitNorms(true);
    TYPE_STORED.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS);
    TYPE_STORED.setNumericType(FieldType.NumericType.DOUBLE);
    TYPE_STORED.setStored(true);
    TYPE_STORED.freeze();
}
```

which does not have DocValues.

Comment: How are you getting the value from the document's field? For numeric types it should be with `doc.getField("stars").numericValue().doubleValue();`

Comment: Using this new FieldType seems to work, but now I am no longer able to print the double value. Later in my application i want to display the double "stars" field, but when I call doc.getValues("stars") i get the heap position I guess ( [Ljava.lang.String;@799d4f69  ) and I am not able to return the original double value. I have also tried with  doc.getField("stars") and with doc.getField("stars").numericValue().doubleValue(); but all I get is a nullpointer exception. Why does this happen if the FieldType is stored?

Comment: `Document.getValues()` returns an array of Strings, so you need to iterate through that. is `doc.getField("stars")` returning `null` or `doc.getField("stars").numericValue()`?

Comment: Oops my bad, after reindexing `doc.getField("stars").numericValue()` works pretty well. Of course. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @user1071777 I've encountered another similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705559/367988 but recommending to create two separate fields. Does your solution give the same result?

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, here is a shortcut for the answer given by @user1071777 :

```
private static final FieldType DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED = new FieldType(LongField.TYPE_STORED);

static {
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.setDocValuesType(DocValuesType.NUMERIC);
    DOUBLE_FIELD_TYPE_STORED_SORTED.freeze();
}
```

The constructor which receives a fieldType will copy all of the properties  already set on stored type.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a DoubleField, but ended up solving the problem by using a DoubleDocValuesField() instead.