# Use SortedSetDocValuesField to sort multiple fields - Error: unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field

Tags: java, sorting, jsf, lucene

I am just implementing a search with Lucene 5.5.0 for a JSF web application. In the application, several user can edit documents and very simple (only date and user name) editing journal will be created. Example:

```
2017-02-10 user15
2017-02-01 user14
2017-01-15 user15
```

Now I want to have a search functionality where a user can look for his own editings - sorted by the date of editing. Looking, but I have problems with the SORTING. Note that I have several editing entries in each document.

My java code for index writing:

```
doc.add(new StoredField(fieldName, fieldValue));
doc.add(new SortedSetDocValuesField(fieldName, new BytesRef(fieldValue)));
```

My code for sorting:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("UserID", SortField.Type.STRING));
docs = searcher.search(finalQuery, hitsPerPage, sort);
```

The indexing is working, but if I am searching for something, I get the following error message:

```
unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field 'UserID' (expected=SORTED).
Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
```

The error message says I should use docvalues - but I am already doing this with `SortedSetDocValuesField`. The actual question to you is how to get rid of this error message.

My code is [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695307/sortiing-string-field-alphabetically-in-lucene-5-0) , but I changed the `SortedDocValuesField` to `SortedSETDocValuesField`. Otherwise, I get the error `DocValuesField "UserID" appears more than once in this document (only one value is allowed per field)` when creating the index.

So, do I have to set special settings for SortedSETDocValuesField? I also had a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451111/lucene-5-sort-problems-uninvertedreader-and-docvalues), but it is not useful for me as I am using Strings (want to sort it in alphabetical row) and not Double. Thank you very much in advance :) .

Not really important for the question, but for understanding how my search works for this field:

In the field "UserID", I am storing a String "2017-02-10===user15" which I split with a custom Analyzer (only for the index) to the Tokens "2017-02-10" and "user15". Then I add these Strings to each document. When searching, the result (the determination of the results is already working) should be sorted in descending order (highest/newest date first).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a [`SortedSetSortField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SortedSetSortField.html), instead of a standard `SortField`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the error message is gone now :) . But the sorting does not act how I want. I totally have no idea how Lucene sorts the items now. I gave Lucene the field "UserID" and it uses UTF8SortedAsUnicodeComparator (which should be ok for strings), but do you have any debugging hints to find out which strings (the VALUES, not the fieldName) Lucene sorts exactly? I use Strings like "2017-02-10===user15", maybe it gets confused because of that.